# How to find the length of the focal chord that makes an angle $\theta$ with the axis of parabola $y^2=4ax$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

A focal chord of $y^2=4ax$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the axis of the parabola. How do I find the length of the chord?

I tried using the parametric equation but couldn't go further.

Comment: Same doubt. The first answer's method is easily available online but I want to know a method using geometry.

Comment: [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/prove-that-the-length-of-focal-chord-of-parabola-y24ax-making-an-angle-a-with/)

Comment: The answer is $4a\csc^2 \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is angle of chord with x axis

Comment: You are right, I thought about it and my edit invalidates the first answer to the question. When I first changed the title, I thought it would be harmless since the asker left the site. @Blue

Comment: @Buraian: FYI, I have posted [a geometric solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198078/409).

Answer (score 3):

Consider a parabola with focus $F$ and focal chord $\overline{PQ}$ making a non-obtuse angle $\theta$ with the axis. Drop perpendiculars from $F$, $P$, $Q$ to $F'$, $P'$, $Q'$ on the directrix; and "raise" a perpendicular from $F$ to $M$ on the directrix.

[image]

By the focus-directrix definition of the parabola, $\overline{FP}\cong\overline{PP'}$ and $\overline{FQ}\cong\overline{QQ'}$. We conclude that $\square FPP'M$ and $\square FQQ'M$ are right-angled kites, with $\overline{MF}\cong\overline{MP'}\cong\overline{MQ'}$ and $\angle FMF'=\theta$. Calculating $|P'Q'|$ in two ways, we have

> $$|PQ|\sin\theta = 2\,|FF'|\csc\theta \qquad\to\qquad |PQ|=2\,|FF'|\csc^2\theta \tag{$\star$}$$

Note that focus-directrix distance $|FF'|$ is twice the focus-vertex distance, which is represented by $a$ in the formula $y^2=4ax$; so, in comparable notation, $(\star)$ becomes $|PQ|=4a\csc^2\theta$. $\square$

Comment: How is the horizontal pink line equal to $2|FF'| \csc \theta$, rest I understand

Comment: @Buraian: As mentioned, $\square FPP'M$ and $\square FQQ'M$ are right angled kites, which imply $\overline{MF}\cong\overline{MP'}$ and $\overline{MF}\cong\overline{MQ'}$, hence $|P'Q'|=2|MF|$. If it's not clear why the quadrilaterals are kites, draw $\overline{MP}$ and $\overline{MQ}$ to break them into pairs of right angles; each pair has a congruent legs and a common hypotenuse, so are congruent triangles. That $|MF|=|FF'|\csc\theta$ is elementary right-triangle trigonometry in $\triangle MFF'$. ... Does that help?

Comment: Ok I read it again with a fresh mind, firstly I don't get why two side pair equal + angle equal implies that last two sides are equal in the quadrilateral (and hence the claim it is right angled kite)

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- What are the coordinates of the focus of the parabola?
- What is the equation of the line that makes an angle $\theta$ with the $y$-axis and goes through the focus?  (This line contains the focal chord given in the question.)
- At what two points does this line intersect the parabola?
- Finally, what is the distance between these two points?