# Alternate geometrical proof that tangent bisects angle of parabola

Tags: solution-verification, conic-sections

I'm trying to understand the proof hinted at by the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756391/tangent-on-parabola-bisects-angle) on the main post here:

> A slightly different way to prove it is to consider the perpendicular bisector of FQ. Because it is a parabola, P must lie on this perpendicular bisector, and for the same reason (this needs a small effort) no other point of the parabola lies on this perpendicular bisector. Then prove that it is a tangent.

I got the fact that $P$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector, we can argue by the property that distance to focus of point= distance of point to directrix. But, how do I show that no other point lies in common with it and parabola, then further, that the line is a tangent?

---

**Possible proof:** It must be that if there is another point, then the shortest distance along the common normal line must be zero. However, notice that the normal of the parabola is a bijective function with the parameter, i.e: a given normal has a very specific parameter value which would output it. Hence, it follows that there can only be one parameter value where the normal are in common.

I am not sure if the above explanation is rigorous though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to prove that the tangent at $P$ bisects $\angle FPQ$ (see figure).

The simplest one is probably proving the converse (and I think this is also the proof hinted at in that comment): if line $PT$ is the bisector of $\angle FPQ$, then it touches the parabola only at $P$, all its other points being external to the parabola, and is thus tangent. This follows from a simple observation: if you take any point $P'\ne P$ on line $PT$ and its projection $H$ on the directrix, then
$FP'=P'Q>P'H$ and $P'$ is then outside the parabola.

Another way requires to [prove as a lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953161/the-portion-of-the-tangent-to-any-conic-intercepted-between-the-point-of-contact/3953791#3953791) that $\angle PFK=90°$, where $K$ is the intersection of the tangent at $P$ with the directrix (and this is true for all conic sections, not only parabolas). From that it follows that $\triangle PFK\cong \triangle PQK$ and $PK$ is thus the bisector of $\angle FPQ$.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I had a similar idea but how would one justify $P'Q>P'H$, it is clear from geometry but can an explicit written reason be given?

Comment: [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198078/688539)

Comment: Well, hypotenuse $P'Q$ is longer than leg $P'H$, because [in any triangle the side opposite the greater angle is greater](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI19.html).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Why is FP' = P'Q ? @Intelligentipauca

Comment: @Paracetamol Because triangles $FPP'$ and $QPP'$ are congruent.

Comment: Thanks understood , can we similairily do in other proof problems proving the converse and then say we proved ? Or it will not work in some cases ? @Intelligentipauca

Comment: @Paracetamol It doesn't always work. It does in this case, just because the bisector of an angle is unique and the tangent at $P$ is unique too.

Comment: @Paracetamol To be rigorous,  one should end the proof with a RAA argument: suppose the tangent at $P$ is NOT the bisector; by the above proof, however, the bisector IS a tangent at $P$, hence you would have two different tangents at the same point, which is absurd.

Comment: Hmm finally understood what you meant thanks @Intelligentipauca

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The parabola in the diagram from the linked page has the equation $ \ y = \frac{x^2}{4f} + f \ , $ with $ \ f  \ $ being the distance from the vertex to the directrix on the $ \ x-$ axis.  So the slope of the tangent line at $ \ P (x_0 , \frac{x_0^2}{4f} + f) \ $ is $ \ \frac{x_0}{2f} \ $ .  The line through the focus $ \ F \ $ and the point $ \ P \ $ has the slope $$ \ \frac{[\frac{x_0^2}{4f} + f] - 2f}{x_0} \ = \  \frac{x_0}{4f}  - \frac{f}{x_0} \ \ . $$  The tangent line then makes an angle $ \ \theta \ $ to the $ \ x-$ axis given by
$ \ \tan \theta \ = \ \frac{x_0}{2f} \ ; $ this makes the angle $ \ \angle QPT \ = \ \phi \ =    \  \theta - 90º \ \ , $ so $ \ \cot \phi \ = \ -\frac{x_0}{2f} \ \ . $

The line $ \ PF \ $ makes an angle $ \ \psi \ $  to the $ \ x-$ axis , so $ \ \angle QPF \ = \ \chi \ =    \  \psi - 90º \ \   $ has $ \ \cot \chi \ = \ - \left[ \ \frac{x_0}{4f}  - \frac{f}{x_0} \ \right] \ \ . $

The double-angle formula for cotangent is readily shown to be $$ \cot 2\alpha \ \ = \ \ \frac{\cot^2 \alpha \ - \ 1}{2 \ \cot \alpha} \ \ . $$
Applying this, we obtain
$$ \cot 2\phi \ \ = \ \ \frac{\left( -\frac{x_0}{2f} \right)^2 \ - \ 1}{2 \ · \ \left( -\frac{x_0}{2f}  \right)} \ \ =  \ \ -\frac{f}{x_0} · \ \left[ \ \left( \frac{x_0}{2f} \right)^2 \ - \ 1 \ \right] \ \ = \ \   \frac{f}{x_0} \  - \ \frac{x_0}{4f} \ \ = \ \ \cot \chi \  . $$

Hence, the tangent line $ \ PT \ $ bisects the angle $ \ \angle QPF \ \ . $  [Sorry that it's not a *purely* geometric argument...]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still am seeking a geometric arguement

Comment: Assuming that a light ray from the focus will travel on a vertical line after reflection, is the same as assuming what you want to prove. One usually does the reverse: from the angle bisecting property of the tangent, the reflection behaviour described above can be derived.

Comment: While I'll say that that isn't the way I've seen the reflection principle obtained, I will withdraw the argument and try to find a different approach.